# MySQL Generate unique identifier before insert

Tags: mysql

I writing a program that logs packets of data to a MySQL database.

The program also forwards these packets and speed is absolutely critical.
I want to be able to forward these packets as soon as posible.

Logging to the database is done in the background with batch inserts of queued up packets.

I don't want to wait for the database to write the packets to disc before forwarding them, but I need a way of identifing the individual packets.

How can I do this?  Basicaly I need to generate a unique identifier for each packet without using Auto_Increment as I would have to wait for the database then.

The only unique thing about the individual packets is the time in which they came in, but using time as an identifer seems like a bad idea (for example if time gets set backwards by NTP/User/LeapSecond/etc...)

Is there another way?  Can you quickly reserve unique identifers from the database without needing to go the disc?

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not go to disk to retrieve the next value, see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-traditional.html). An auto incremented primary key is definitely your most efficient option.

Comment: Interesting. But can you get an auto incremented primary key value without doing a full insert (until later when you write all columns)?

Comment: The program is written in what language?

Comment: It's currently written in C#